# AT command Send Expect via Minicom does not recognize quotations

Tags: linux, at-command, minicom

Currently I have the following script running via minicom.

```
minicom -b 115200 -D $MODEM_DEVNODE -t vt100 -S csq.txt -C csq_results.txt < escape.txt

csq.txt

send AT+QENG="servingcell"
expect "OK"
sleep 5
send AT+COPS?
expect "+COPS:
```

When I enter AT+QENG="servingcell" manually I am able to see the desired serving cell properties. However, when I run the script I see an error. Can someone explain to me why it does not like the ""  in the script?

Comment: When quotation marks are meaningful to the scripting language, actually including a quotation character in the data requires something extra.  So your question is effectively "How do I escape a quotation mark character in a minicom script file?"

Comment: The error is probably from the unpaired quotation mark in the last line.

Comment: Documentation of minicom scripting language -- https://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to escape the quotations

```
send AT+QENG=\"servingcell\"
```